# Unknown Reason for syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to code a number guessing game that tracks my guesses. I am having trouble with a syntax error with the append function. Here is the segment of my code with the error. I am getting an error on the `list1.append(userGuess)` line:

```
list1 = []

while userGuess != randomNumber and userGuess != "q":

if userGuess > randomNumber:
    userGuess = (int( raw_input( 'Your guess is too high! Guess another integer or type "q" to quit\n> ' ))
    list1.append(userGuess)

if userGuess < randomNumber:
    userGuess = (int( raw_input( 'Your guess is too low! Guess another integer or type "q" to quit\n> ' ))
    list1.append(userGuess)
```

`userGuess` is an integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a closing bracket on the previous lines (both of the lines with `raw_input`).

Generally it's a good idea to look at the previous line than that shown in the error message, because expressions in brackets can span multiple lines.

On an unrelated note, your code seems a bit repetitive. You might want to compress it, e.g.:

```
while userGuess != randomNumber and userGuess != "q":

    userGuess = int(raw_input('Your guess is too {}!'
          'Guess another integer or type "q" to quit\n> '.format(
                 'high' if userGuess > randomNumber else 'low')))
    list1.append(userGuess)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there should be one more closing parenthesis at the end of each `raw_input` line.